# Automotive app rejected due to login credentials not provided, when there is no sign-in

Tags: android, android-automotive, automotive

I have submitted an Android Automotive app to play store. It was rejected due to "login credentials", and it says in the rejection mail that we have to provide login credentials. However, our application does not require login/sign-in. This is specified in the "App Access" section under "App Content" in play console.

I filed an appeal to Google where I wrote that we don't require login, but they answered the same.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not tag Google?

Comment: It says that the Google tag is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
After many unsuccessful attempts of contacting Google to get an answer, it turned out that the only thing to do was to ask ChatGPT. As previously stated, Google rejected our app based on "lack of login credentials" to use to login to test the application. However we did not have a login, and we had also ticked the "no login needed to access the app" checkbox. ChatGPT answered that this rejection message can be generated if the "permissions and resources" of the app has not been specified correctly. It turned out that since we use location data, we had to go to "data safety" and tick the location data boxes there. This ofcourse makes sense, but I will say that Google mislead us with the "missing login credentials" rejection.

Hope this can be of help to someone else as well!